# Create a connection to SQL Server DB inside Servlet request Thows "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"

Tags: java

Create a connection to SQL from a Java file with `main()` class defined works fine but calling the method inside a `doPost()` in Java Servlet throwing Error as

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

Working Code

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Connect{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
      {

        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=UserDB";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"sa","XXXXXXX");

        String query =" SELECT * FROM Login";


        Statement myStatement = null;
        myStatement = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = myStatement.executeQuery(query);

        while(result.next()){
            System.out.println("User name = " + result.getString("userID"));
            System.out.println("User password = " + result.getString("userPassword"));
        }

      }
}
```

**Now Working Code inside Servlet**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String userName= request.getParameter("username");
        String password= request.getParameter("password");

        try {
            if( **new DbQuery().isValidLogin(userName, password)**)
            {
                response.getWriter().println("Welcome " +userName);
            }

            else{
                response.getWriter().println("Please Enter a valid User name and Password");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

In the above code  `new DbQuery().isValidLogin(userName, password)`  creates a DB connection and the Class used as

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
```

On hitting the above line ........ ERROR

please help.

Comment: Check your web project if the jar is present in classpath or not?

Comment: You need to add the SQL driver to your class path.

Comment: Share your isValidLogin() method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put sqljdbc jar in your application server. For example if you are using tomcat server, go to the directory where you have installed the tomcat, open the LIB directory and make sure you have sqljdbc jar exists over there.

Comment: Glad to hear that.. needs a favor, can you please mark this comment as answer and provide +1 :)

Comment: I did it on same day , but it says only visible if I get 15 points :)

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error while deploying the similar application in Tomcat Server. Put the relevant jdbc jar in the lib folder of Tomcat. It should work fine.